# javascript login into a webpage without browser only with requests scrape / webcrawl

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, request, fetch

i want to login into a webpage with react-native. There is no public API. This webpage is not from me. 
I ask them, if it is okay to do this and they said yes. So this is not a hacker question.
It is a mobile Provider and I want to build an App to show the data from there.
I looked up with burp to the requests.
Here is a photo:
[image]

I coppied the request as curl and converted it to fetch. 
I only get the first cookie (selfservice) from the request. 
This is my code for first request:

```
 fetch('https://onlineservice.klarmobil.de/checklogin', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        body: 'f_username=xxx&f_password=xxx',
        headers: {
            'Host': 'onlineservice.klarmobil.de',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'Accept-Language': 'de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Referer': 'https://www.klarmobil.de/',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Content-Length': '68',
            'Origin': 'https://www.klarmobil.de',
            'Connection': 'close'

        }
    })
```

The second cookie i cant get with fetch. (kmPost)
All i want is, get the html code.

I dont know I am doing it in the right way...
Maybe somebody can help me?

Maybe there is a completly other way to simulate a login without cookies?

If somebody can give me a solution with plain javascript/ node i will accept the answer